# access to element data

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular5

I have a mat table.

Data comes from json:

```
myData=[{
    name: 'MyName1', 
    options: [{
       optionName: 'option1 name'    
    },{
       optionName: 'option2 name'
    }]
  }, {
    name: 'MyName2',
    options:[]
}]
dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<MyData>(myData));
```

Depending on options.length mat-cell changes:

```
<mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource">
   <ng-container matColumnDef="options">
       <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Options </mat-header-cell>
       <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
            <ng-container *ngIf="element.options.length > 0; then div1; else div2"></ng-container>
       </mat-cell> 
   </ng-container>
</mat-table>

<ng-template #div1>
   <div> with options {{element.name}}</div
</ng-template>
<ng-template #div2>
   <div> no options {{element.name}}</div
</ng-template>
```

And my error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
```

So, I should pass "element" from ngIf to my ng-templates, but I can't find how to do it.

Comment: You should reformat your data by `MatTableDataSource` and define your displayed column. View [this](https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it, my problem was I defined ng-template outside the loop.

It should be:

```
 <mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource">
   <ng-container matColumnDef="options">
       <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Options </mat-header-cell>
       <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
            <ng-container *ngIf="element.options.length > 0; then div1; else div2"></ng-container>
                <ng-template #div1>
                   <div> with options {{element.name}}</div>
                 </ng-template>
                 <ng-template #div2>
                     <div> no options {{element.name}}</div>
                 </ng-template>
       </mat-cell> 
   </ng-container>
</mat-table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be having typesafe `?`

```
<ng-template #div1>
   <div> with options {{element?.name}}</div
</ng-template>
<ng-template #div1>
   <div> no options {{element?.name}}</div
</ng-template>
```

Comment: can you add the `element` object to the post

Comment: element is each element in dataSource, first one has name "Name1" and the second one has "Name2"

Comment: I guess `dataSource` should be of array type

Comment: did you print the element as json object `{{ element | json }}`  and see what is seen in the HTML

Comment: element has data in ng-container  but it hasn't in ng-template

Answer (score 0):

Could you do something like this? It may not be as elegant but it should be functional.

```
   <mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource">
       <ng-container matColumnDef="options">
           <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Options </mat-header-cell>
           <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                <div *ngIf="element.options.length > 0">
                  <div> with options {{element.name}}</div
                </div>
                <div *ngIf="element.options.length == 0>
                  <div> no options {{element.name}}</div
                </div>
           </mat-cell> 
       </ng-container>
    </mat-table>
```

EDIT: I had a previous answer but I realized it was wrong and replaced it with this.